# Is it possible to detect where a canvas is clicked on and remove an item after it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a set of javascript code which creates a circle object and then pushes it onto the canvas. Is there a way so that if a user were to click on one of the circles the object would disappear?
Here's my Javascript Code

```
// get a reference to the canvas and its context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// set canvas to equal window size
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

// newly spawned objects start at Y=25
var spawnLineY = 25;

// spawn a new object every 1500ms
var spawnRate = 1500;

// when was the last object spawned
var lastSpawn = -1;

// this array holds all spawned object
var objects = [];

// save the starting time (used to calc elapsed time)
var startTime = Date.now();

// start animating
animate();

function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        /**
         * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will 
be reset when 
         * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
         */
}
function spawnRandomObject() {

// select a random type for this new object
var t;

// About Math.random()
// Math.random() generates a semi-random number
// between 0-1. So to randomly decide if the next object
// will be A or B, we say if the random# is 0-.49 we
// create A and if the random# is .50-1.00 we create B
var random;
random = Math.random();
if (random < 0.75 && random > .50) {
    t = "red";
} else if (random > .75) {
    t = "blue";
} else if (random < .50 && random > .25) {
    t = "purple"
} else if (random < .25) {
    t = "green"
}

// create the new object
var object = {

    // set this objects type
    type: t,
    // set x randomly but at least 15px off the canvas edges
    x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30) + 15,
    // set y to start on the line where objects are spawned
    y: spawnLineY,
    downspeed: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 5)/100,
    radius: Math.floor((Math.random() * 175) + 5),
    onclick : alert('blah'),
}

// add the new object to the objects[] array
objects.push(object);
}
// the code to make the circle disappear would go here
popBalloon()


function animate() {

// get the elapsed time
var time = Date.now();

// see if its time to spawn a new object
if (time > (lastSpawn + spawnRate)) {
    lastSpawn = time;
    spawnRandomObject();
}

// request another animation frame
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

// clear the canvas so all objects can be 
// redrawn in new positions
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// draw the line where new objects are spawned
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, spawnLineY);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, spawnLineY);
ctx.stroke();
// move each object down the canvas
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var object = objects[i];
    object.y += object.downspeed;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, object.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = object.type;
    ctx.fill();
}

}
resizeCanvas();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the mouse click position on the canvas

```
// assuming canvas is already defined and references an DOM canvas Element
const mouse = {x ;0,y :0, clicked : false};
function mouseClickEvent(event){
    mouse.x = event.offsetX;
    mouse.y = event.offsetY;
    mouse.clicked = true;
}
canvas.addEventListener("click",mouseClickEvent);
```

Then in your render loop check for mouse clicks

```
if(mouse.clicked){
      // do what is needed
    mouse.clicked = false; /// clear the clicked flag
}
```

To find out if a point is inside a circle

```
// points is {x,y}
// circle is {x,y,r} where r is radius
// returns true if point touches circle
function isPointInCircle(point,circle){
     var x = point.x - circle.x;
     var y = point.y - circle.y;
     return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) <= circle.r;
}
```

Or with ES6

```
function isPointInCircle(point,circle){
     return Math.hypot(point.x - circle.x, point.y - circle.y) <= circle.r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how to get the mouse x and y position but if you can get that this function should help detect collision

```
function checkColision()// if mouse collides with object
{
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
     // get the distance between mouse and object
    var xRange = Math.abs(mouse.x - object[i].x);//abslute value so no negative numbers
    var yRange = Math.abs(mouse.y - object[i].y);

    if (xRange < MIN_COLISION_RANGE && yRange < MIN_COLISION_RANGE)
    {
        object.splice(i, 1);//remove object
        i--;//go back one iteration
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out.

Comment: You will need to get the min collision range yourself , if you are using circles it would be the radius of the circle. and to get the mouse x and y apparently you can just do e.clientX, e.clientY

Comment: I made a mistake in my last comment, if the minimum collision range is the radius of the circle you will have to set the circles x and y to be the center of the circle, as the x and y are from the top left corner of the object

Comment: I'm getting the error "mouse is not defined". Any ideas?